# How to assign special characters to a variable in C?

Tags: c

How to assign a special character to a variable in C?
I am trying to assign variable symbol a character like ~~~~~ or @@@@@ or ***** or ;;;;;;.
What I did was`char symbol = "~~~~~~~~~~";`
but this did not work, so I tried to change double quotes to single like this:

```
char symbol = '@@@@@@@@@';
```

but this did not work either;

Comment: `const char* c = "@@@@@@@";`

Comment: A `char` can represent *one* character, like `'@'` or `'a'`. All your "characters" consist of several characters. You'll get better help if you explain what you're going to do with them.

Answer (score 4):

It works, but you are trying to put multiple character into a single one which doesn't make sense.

Try:

```
char symbol = '@';
const char symbols[] = "@@@@@@";
const char* symbols2 = "@@@@@@@";
```

Note that you need to use single quotes `'` for single characters and double quotes `"` for strings.

Also note that char is usually defined as 8-bit integer so you can only hold the usual ASCII characters. If you need Unicode you should use char arrays to accommodate all the bits needed and preferably use a library that  takes care of handling, conversions, and any other operation you might want to do.

Comment: no no I am using these variables in an if statement and I change the value according to the if.

Comment: You can copy char arrays. I use const because the pointers will point to compiler static constants in the case above. Allocate a modifiable array `char * symbol = (char*)malloc(max_length_of_your_string+1);` then use memcpy to copy whatever you want there. C strings are kinda horrible and easy to mess up. If you can use C++ strings it will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a *pointer to char* if you want to assign multiple values.

```
const char *smth = "@@@@";
```

If you need only one, then simply `char smth = '@';`